# NSString Converting @ to %40 on Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Currently I'm using Resty (http://projects.lukeredpath.co.uk/resty/) to build my own API wrapper for Objective-C.

I digress however, in the request itself, I am able to determine what is actually being sent and it seems that the NSString *email (I scan for an @ to make sure it is a legitimate email before storing in another NSString) is actually changed.

An example, joe@example.com has been scanned for the @, and then sent to the NSString *email for the request. However, when I send the actual GET request, the NSString is changed to joe%40example.com.

Is this due to the Resty request, or do I have to encode/decode the NSString before the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should URL decode and then perform any validation tasks.

Here is what their documentation has:

> NSData or any other data-encodable
>   payloads set the request body as-is;
>   encodable payloads will be encoded
>   using UTF8

http://projects.lukeredpath.co.uk/resty/documentation.html

Comment: Hey! I've already tried doing so by using NSString *encoded = [email stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; and sending encoded as the param. Still, the %40 is still there and not an @.

Comment: So you're saying I could convert the NSString I'm using to NSData and it'd automagically be sent as whatever I set the dataUsingEncoding too?

Comment: Here is another (Out of the box, Resty supports NSDictionary and NSData payloads as well as any object that can be converted to NSData by calling the dataUsingEncoding: method (such as NSString).  You need to pass NSData payloads by converting your string by calling dataUsingEncoding.

Comment: Okay, that's fine, but I'm not actually sending a payload. I'm only sending the parameters, it's a GET request.